# Angular MatBadge not showing full number when it's higher than 99

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I have a notification count that shows the quantity of notifications for a specific user, but when the user has more than 99 notifications, the matBadge doesn't show the full number, it shows '1...', like the image below. Can anyone tell how to fix? I want to display the full number.

[image]

I tried to change da position of the badge or increasing the badge area but it did not work

Comment: you need to overwrite and make badge bit bigger
.mat-badge-*** { width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 28px;}
depending on which badge you are using replace *** with one of these values. 'small' | 'medium' | 'large'

Angular is great. but unfortunately, Material library is bit funky. well at least it is free :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a fixed `width` and `height` is not the best option out there.

Add the following CSS in `styles.scss`:

```
.mat-badge-content {
  width: auto !important; // Set the width to auto
  height: auto !important; // Set the height to auto
  min-width: 22px; // But the width should be at least 22px (in case the number is 99 or less)
  min-height: 22px; // But the height should be at least 22px (in case the number is 99 or less)
  aspect-ratio: 1/1; // Keep the circle shape
  display: flex; // Required in order for align-items and justify-content to work
  align-items: center; // Center the number vertically
  justify-content: center; // Center the number horizontally
  padding: 2px; // Add a bit of padding so that the number is not placed all the way to the border of the circle
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

See the [live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/9wske1?file=src%2Fstyles.scss).